# How to set referrer using WWW::Scripter module in perl?

Tags: javascript, perl, cookies, http-referer, lwp

Simple code for my crawler is:

```
      #!/usr/bin/perl -w

      use WWW::Scripter;

      $w = new WWW::Scripter('agent' => 'myAgent');
      $w->use_plugin('JavaScript');

      ### need to set a referrer header here ###

      $w->get('http://website-url');

      print $w->content, "\n";
```

I need to set a **referrer** header before `get` is executed. Alternatively I will need also set other headers, such as **cookie**, etc. I don't see in [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Scripter) how to do it. There has to be a way, how to set headers. How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WWW::Scripter](http://search.cpan.org/~sprout/WWW-Scripter-0.025/lib/WWW/Scripter.pod) is a subclass of [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm), so you should be able to use the methods of that class as well. This is how it should look:

```
use strict;   #ALWAYS do this
use warnings; #This too. Allows more control than -w
use WWW::Scripter;

#MODULE->new() is better than new Module() because of possible parsing ambiguity
my $w = WWW::Scripter->new('agent' => 'myAgent');
$w->add_header( Referer => 'http://somesite.com' );
$w->get('http://website-url');
```

Comment: I knew it has to be simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is subclass of `WWW::Mechanize` so:

```
$w->add_header(Referer => "http://...");
```